# Installing gtk3 for Haskell (GHCJS)

Tags: haskell, gtk, cabal, pkg-config, ghcjs

I'm trying to install GHCJS on Mac OSX (Yosemite).  So far, I have updated Alex and Happy and installed gtk2hs-buildtools.  Now when I run `cabal install ghcjs-dom`, I'm told that I need to install pkg-config...

```
~/Haskell/ghcjs-test/domTest: cabal install ghcjs-dom
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring cairo-0.13.1.1...
...
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( SetupMain.hs, dist/setup-wrapper/Main.o )
Linking dist/setup-wrapper/setup ...
Configuring cairo-0.13.1.1...
setup: The program 'pkg-config' version >=0.9.0 is required but it could not
be found.
Failed to install glib-0.13.2.2
Build log ( /Users/markkaravan/.cabal/logs/glib-0.13.2.2.log ):
...
```

Hmmmm, pkg-config eh?

```
~/Haskell/ghcjs-test/domTest: cabal install pkg-config
cabal: There is no package named 'pkg-config'.
```

I then keep running `cabal install ghcjs-dom`, each time hitting a dependency that I then have to google and install via brew.  This happens about 4 or 5 times.  Finally, I'm stuck on gtk.

```
~/Haskell/ghcjs-test/domTest: cabal install ghcjs-dom
Resolving dependencies...
... 
Configuring gtk3-0.14.2...
setup: The pkg-config package 'gtk+-3.0' is required but it could not be
found.
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
ghcjs-dom-0.2.3.1 depends on gtk3-0.14.2 which failed to install.
gtk3-0.14.2 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
webkitgtk3-0.14.1.1 depends on gtk3-0.14.2 which failed to install.
```

After failing to brew install it, I try to install it with cabal:

```
~/Haskell/ghcjs-test/domTest: cabal install gtk
Resolving dependencies...
Downloading gtk-0.14.2...
Configuring gtk-0.14.2...
Building gtk-0.14.2...
Failed to install gtk-0.14.2
Build log ( /Users/markkaravan/.cabal/logs/gtk-0.14.2.log ):
[1 of 2] Compiling SetupWrapper     ( /var/folders/br/4zwhphlx3816v87cc0bb5sxh0000gn/T/cabal-tmp-12417/gtk-0.14.2/SetupWrapper.hs, /var/folders/br/4zwhphlx3816v87cc0bb5sxh0000gn/T/cabal-tmp-12417/gtk-0.14.2/dist/setup/SetupWrapper.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( /var/folders/br/4zwhphlx3816v87cc0bb5sxh0000gn/T/cabal-tmp-12417/gtk-0.14.2/dist/setup/setup.hs, /var/folders/br/4zwhphlx3816v87cc0bb5sxh0000gn/T/cabal-tmp-12417/gtk-0.14.2/dist/setup/Main.o )
Linking /var/folders/br/4zwhphlx3816v87cc0bb5sxh0000gn/T/cabal-tmp-12417/gtk-0.14.2/dist/setup/setup ...
[1 of 2] Compiling Gtk2HsSetup      ( Gtk2HsSetup.hs, dist/setup-wrapper/Gtk2HsSetup.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( SetupMain.hs, dist/setup-wrapper/Main.o )
Linking dist/setup-wrapper/setup ...
Configuring gtk-0.14.2...
Building gtk-0.14.2...
Preprocessing library gtk-0.14.2...
[  1 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.ModelView.Sequence ( Graphics/UI/Gtk/ModelView/Sequence.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/ModelView/Sequence.o )
[  2 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.Gdk.Enums ( dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Gdk/Enums.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Gdk/Enums.o )
[  3 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.General.Enums ( dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/General/Enums.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/General/Enums.o )
[  4 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.General.Threading ( Graphics/UI/Gtk/General/Threading.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/General/Threading.o )
[  5 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.Signals ( dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Signals.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Signals.o )
[  6 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.Types ( dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Types.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Types.o )
[  7 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.General.DNDTypes ( dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/General/DNDTypes.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/General/DNDTypes.o )
[  8 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.Abstract.ContainerChildProperties ( dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Abstract/ContainerChildProperties.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Abstract/ContainerChildProperties.o )
[  9 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.Embedding.Types ( dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Embedding/Types.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Embedding/Types.o )
[ 10 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.Embedding.Embedding ( dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Embedding/Embedding.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Embedding/Embedding.o )
[ 11 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.ModelView.Types ( dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/ModelView/Types.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/ModelView/Types.o )
[ 12 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.Gdk.PixbufData ( Graphics/UI/Gtk/Gdk/PixbufData.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Gdk/PixbufData.o )
[ 13 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.Gdk.PixbufAnimation ( dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Gdk/PixbufAnimation.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Gdk/PixbufAnimation.o )
[ 14 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.Builder ( dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Builder.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Builder.o )
[ 15 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.Abstract.Separator ( Graphics/UI/Gtk/Abstract/Separator.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Abstract/Separator.o )
[ 16 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.Abstract.Scrollbar ( Graphics/UI/Gtk/Abstract/Scrollbar.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Abstract/Scrollbar.o )
[ 17 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.Abstract.Scale ( dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Abstract/Scale.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Abstract/Scale.o )
[ 18 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.Abstract.Object ( dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Abstract/Object.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Abstract/Object.o )
[ 19 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.Abstract.Paned ( dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Abstract/Paned.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Abstract/Paned.o )
[ 20 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.General.Structs ( dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/General/Structs.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/General/Structs.o )
[ 21 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.Abstract.Range ( dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Abstract/Range.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Abstract/Range.o )
[ 22 of 209] Compiling Graphics.UI.Gtk.Embedding.Plug ( dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Embedding/Plug.hs, dist/build/Graphics/UI/Gtk/Embedding/Plug.o )

Graphics/UI/Gtk/Embedding/Plug.chs:120:6:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Ptr ()’
                with actual type ‘Maybe DrawWindow’
    In the first argument of ‘gtk_plug_new’, namely
      ‘(fromNativeWindowId (fromMaybe nativeWindowIdNone socketId))’
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
      ‘gtk_plug_new
         (fromNativeWindowId (fromMaybe nativeWindowIdNone socketId))’

Graphics/UI/Gtk/Embedding/Plug.chs:137:6:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Ptr ()’
                with actual type ‘Maybe DrawWindow’
    In the second argument of ‘\ (Display arg1) arg2
                                 -> withForeignPtr arg1
                                    $ \ argPtr1 -> gtk_plug_new_for_display argPtr1 arg2’, namely
      ‘(fromNativeWindowId (fromMaybe nativeWindowIdNone socketId))’
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
      ‘(\ (Display arg1) arg2
          -> withForeignPtr arg1
             $ \ argPtr1 -> gtk_plug_new_for_display argPtr1 arg2)
         display
         (fromNativeWindowId (fromMaybe nativeWindowIdNone socketId))’

Graphics/UI/Gtk/Embedding/Plug.chs:151:3:
    Couldn't match type ‘Ptr ()’ with ‘Maybe DrawWindow’
    Expected type: IO (Maybe DrawWindow)
      Actual type: IO (Ptr ())
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
      ‘(\ (Plug arg1)
          -> withForeignPtr arg1 $ \ argPtr1 -> gtk_plug_get_id argPtr1)
         (toPlug self)’
    In the expression:
      liftM toNativeWindowId
      $ (\ (Plug arg1)
           -> withForeignPtr arg1 $ \ argPtr1 -> gtk_plug_get_id argPtr1)
          (toPlug self)
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
gtk-0.14.2 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Now I'm lost.  Google is coming up short.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hmmm I wonder why ghcjs needs gtk.  Those seem to be pretty... incompatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `brew install gtk+3`.  Doing `cabal install gtk` will only install the Haskell bindings for gtk.  That said, the reason you are getting the build errors when trying to install gtk (which you don't need) is because you are missing the `-fhave-quartz-gtk` flag, which is needed for mac.

Comment: it seems to have installed gtk-0.14.2, but when I run `cabal install ghcjs-dom` it fails, saying `Failed to install gtk3-0.14.2`.  Were you able to get away with gtk rather than gtk3?

Comment: Sorry, I should have read your question more carefully.  You need the gtk3 Haskell package, which depends on the gtk+-3.0 system package.  You can get gtk+-3.0 via `brew install gtk+3` on Mac (assuming you have homebrew, which if you don't, you definitely should get it).  I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Well that worked so I'm marking this as correct.  Now it's stuck on `Failed to install webkitgtk3-0.14.1.1`...is there a list of the dependencies for these GHCJS packages?

Comment: Try doing `cabal install ghcjs-dom -f-gtk3`.  This will use regular gtk rather than gtk3.  This will now require that you do `cabal install gtk -fhave-quartz-gtk` at some point.

Comment: `Building gtk-0.13.9...Failed to install gtk-0.13.9`  Getttng a similar error

Comment: It seems they want an older version of gtk for some reason.  You'll have to explicitly specify the version number, such as `cabal install gtk-0.13.9 -fhave-quartz-gtk`

Comment: That installed gtk-0.13.9.  When I run `cabal install ghcjs-dom -f-gtk3`, I get `Failed to install webkit-0.14.1.1`.  When I try to install that version with `cabal install gtk-0.14.1.1 -fhave-quartz-gtk` I get `cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:`